# d3 text-wrap plugin changes coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, angular, d3.js, svg

I would wrap dynamic text.

I'm using [d3-textwrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-textwrap) plugin.

I tried to apply what mentioned in doc

```
let textWrap;
let d3Text1 = d3.selectAll(stations);
textWrap = d3wrap.textwrap().bounds({ height: 100, width: 100 });
d3Text1.call(textWrap); // commenting this will make initial position but no wrap
```

the plugin is working but the text is getting moved from it's initial position*

Before text wrapping

[image: before]

And after text wrapping

[image]

here a reproduction on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d3-textplugin?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems the position is not an incorrect place, there are many ways to fix that, the best way you must make a correction on how you append text in that SVG, to fix that you must create a group to hold the text, this is a simple way.

Replace your updateStationsName function to this :

```
updateStationsName(stations: any, svgTitleDOM: HTMLElement) {
    let textWrap;
    let d3Text1 = d3.selectAll(stations);
    textWrap = d3wrap.textwrap().bounds({ height: 100, width: 100 })

    d3Text1.each(function(d,i){
        // Select the text
        var text = d3.select(this).text() 
        // Get transform position
        var trans = d3.select(this).attr('transform')
        // Remove text
        d3.select(this).remove()
        // Create Group with that text in that position
        var a = d3.select('svg').append('g')
        a.attr('transform', trans )
            .append('text')
            .text(text)
            .call(textWrap);
        // Transform the d3wrap box to make pretty
        a.select('foreignObject').attr('y', -25)
    })

  }
```

**What's wrong with the position?**
the plugin it self destroy your SVG text element and replace to `foreignObject` this destroy all set in position

**Why draw group before append text?** 
it's to make the correct position

Comment: that works when it runs ones, my problem now is `stations` variable is getted from a dom select `this.stations = svgTitleDOM.querySelectorAll('g > text');` so when I trigger again my component `stations`'s length is null. how  can I make that work dynamically. (look at my demo line 17: that DOM select function will not work again

Comment: I think so that plugin won't help me because I should inject  text dynamically on the `text` svg element, but on next change i'll not be able to select it because of precedent change, is that right ? the only solution would be to reload my component ?

Comment: if you have the new problem put it on a new question, because if you put it all on one question there is will be multiple answer, this hard to track, please do it step by step don't forget to make demo code, cheers

Comment: Yes, your response is working for my question even if that makes sides effects on my main code. so I consider it OK.

I have found another simple solution that works on all cases. Using foreignObject and wrap my text into `p` HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to wrap text into `p` HTML element using [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) in svg file instead of `text` element.